# Dashboard background changes itself in Mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My dashboard background changes itself after every reboot! OSX version=10.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Delete your desktop preference file

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

…then log out and back in, then set your desktop wallpaper normally.

Comment: Still not solved. Still ,dashboard background changes itself after wake/reboot though it doesn't change on every wake/reboot!